# Why resetting a form does not clear the bound model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone-stickit

I have bound the text inputs in a form to a Backbone Model using backbone-stickit `bindings`:

```
bindings: {
    '#txtRemarks': 'remarks',
    '#txtFromAccountNumber': 'account_no',
    '#fileChooser':'fileChooser'
}
```

When I reset the form, the values in the text inputs are getting cleared, but the values are still present in the model attributes.

Comment: Marionette doesn't look to have `bindings` by default. Are you using a plugin or an old version?

Comment: backbone.stickit plugin is used

Answer (score 2):

Stickit default handler for input elements is ([source](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.stickit/blob/1c2337baa19cd9b733ab3b13ef9aed5939aa53df/backbone.stickit.js#L436-L443)):

```
{
    selector: 'input',
    events: ['propertychange', 'input', 'change'],
    update: function($el, val) { $el.val(val); },
    getVal: function($el) {
        return $el.val();
    }
}
```

It listens to `'propertychange', 'input', 'change'` and a form reset doesn't trigger these events.

You will need to manually listen to the `reset` event of the form and update the model manually.

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    bindings: { /* ... */ },
    events: {
        '#form-id reset': 'onReset',
    },
    ui: {
        remarks: '.remarks-input',
        account: '.account-input'
    },

    onReset: function(e) {
        this.model.set({
            remarks: this.getUI('remarks').val(),
            account: this.getUI('account').val(),
        });
    }
});
```

Or another trick when dealing with forms is to keep a copy of the model in its initial state, before doing any change. Then you can use the copy to reset the attributes or to check if there were changes.

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    bindings: { /* ... */ },
    events: {
        '#form-id reset': 'onReset',
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.master = this.model.clone();
    },

    onReset: function(e) {
        this.model.set(this.master.attributes);
    },
    getChanges: function() {
        return this.master.changedAttributes(this.model.attributes);
    },
    isDirty: function() {
        return Boolean(this.getChanges());
    },
});
```